# Pie (donut) chart tooltips

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I want to use exactly this d3 donut chart.

[This 3d chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169504/pie-donut-chart-segment-order-in-d3)

However, instead of showing percentage, I'd like to show the raw datas that I am providing.

Ideally, the percentage could be shown (as it is now) and I could show the raw datas for each donut part using an onmouseover tooltip!

Can't make it work.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this,I update the fiddle with tool tip,
Initially add a div to the body i.e.

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip");
```

then whenever user makes a mouseover or mousemove on the paths/arcs do the necessary.

have a look in http://jsfiddle.net/Q3dhh/25/

Comment: I tried this immediately, but I can do only this when I will have 15 reputation points! Sorry :(

Comment: I've had to place `mousemove`/`mouseout` events immediately after `path.append`, as `paths.enter().append("svg:path").on('mousemove',function..)`. It doesn't trigger the mouse event properly